# Objective-C cast baseclass object into specific class

Tags: objective-c

I'm very new in objective C and i want to know if/how what i would like to do is possible.
I have a few classes

```
    @interface A: NSObject
{
    NSString*  Aa;
    NSUInteger Ab;
}

    @interface B: A
{
    NSString*  Ba;
    NSUInteger Bb;
}

    @interface C: A
{
    NSString*  Ca;
    NSUInteger Cb;
}
```

I want to create a function where i expect 'A' type of object and in the implementation check if their type is B or C later. Here's what i want:

```
-(void)doSomething:(A *param)
{
    //do some stuff
    if(param is an instance of B)
    {
        //do stuff with B
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff with C
    }
}
```

How can it be done?

Sincerely,

Zoli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check NSObject's method isKindOfClass:(Class)c
You would do this:

```
-(void)doSomething:(A *)param
{
    //do some stuff
    if([param isKindOfClass:[B class]])
    {
        //do stuff with B (cast will be required to avoid warnings!)
        B *castedB = (B *)param;
        //...
    }
    else if ([param isKindOfClass:[C class]])
    {
        //do stuff with C
        C *castedC = (C *)param;
        //...
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: But ideally, you would use polymorphism and duck typing: define common methods in `A`, then override those methods in `B` and `C` to do `B`- and `C`-specific things. (In which case, depending on whether `A` should know how to do anything itself, you may want to make `A` itself a protocol rather than a class.)

Answer (score 6):

There's four methods you might want to use:

- `isKindOfClass:` tests if an object is a member of class or subclass
- `isMemberOfClass:` same as above, but more specific, doesn't allow subclasses
- `respondsToSelector:` test if an object responds to a given selector, like `[param respondsToSelector:@selector(method:)]`. Useful for duck typing.
- `conformsToProtocol:` test if object implements a protocol.